# Build block matrix from existing matrixes and retain dimnames in r

Tags: r, matrix, block, names

I'm building a block matrix with several smaller matrices that I past along the diagonal with the package Matrix

Let's say I have two matrices

```
m1=matrix(runif(10*10),nrow=10,ncol=10)
m2=matrix(runif(5*5),nrow=5,ncol=5)
```

I create a block matrix with

```
M<-bdiag(m1,m2)
```

**How do I retain the names of columns and rows from the smaller m1 and m2 to the block matrix M?**

note that I need M in a dataframe and therefore I also need at the end to run

```
M<-as.data.frame(as.matrix(M))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Neither m1 nor m2 have names in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `dimnames` back in after running `bdiag` (assuming you mean `Matrix::bdiag`):

```
m1 <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3,dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:3],LETTERS[1:3]))
m2 <- matrix(1:4,nrow=2,dimnames=list(LETTERS[4:5],LETTERS[4:5]))
m1

#  A B C
#A 1 4 7
#B 2 5 8
#C 3 6 9

m2
#  D E
#D 1 3
#E 2 4

out <- bdiag(m1,m2)
dimnames(out) <- Map(c, dimnames(m1), dimnames(m2))
out

#5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#  A B C D E
#A 1 4 7 . .
#B 2 5 8 . .
#C 3 6 9 . .
#D . . . 1 3
#E . . . 2 4
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well (thanks for adding the names too in the code). However in my dataset I cannot turn the object into a matrix at the end with the command M<-as.data.frame(as.matrix(M))   as I have repeated names in different columns (which I need to keep). Any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: @Francesca - You can have repeated column names via `data.frame(as.matrix(out),check.names=FALSE)`, but you can not have repeated row names as a valid data.frame. You'd probably be better off just keeping it as a matrix and not a data.frame.